# Show hide components for a specific page in next js 13 server side component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a Home page for which I have two components, Navbar and Hero. When a user gets login and redirect from home to dashboard, I want to hide this Hero component and make it visible for home page only. What I did, I looked for an approach to hide this component by filtering currently url. I used useRouter hook to get current page url and it gave me an error - **You have a Server Component that imports next/router. Use next/navigation instead**. I used the same as suggested but now am not getting current page url and am getting this error on homepage - **Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')**

The whole idea is to hide this component for all page except home so please either suggest a better way how I can get the same. Below is the code I have used.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'

export const Header = (props) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  //console.log(router.pathname);

  if(router.pathname != "/" )
    return (
        <>
          <header className={props.classes}>
          <Navbar />
          <Hero />
          </header>
        </>
    )
    else {
      return (
        <>
          <header className={props.classes}>
          <Navbar />
          </header>
        </>
    )
    }
}


export default Header
```

Thank in Advance.

Comment: Hi Rohit. Did you find a solution for this one?